# Receiving UDP multicast on macOS Big Sur

Tags: c, sockets, udp, multicast, macos-big-sur

I know this might be the 10.000th question on receiving UDP multicast messages. However, I already got it working half a year ago. The following snippet I got from [http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~eddiea/samples/Multicast/multicast-listen.c.html](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eeddiea/samples/Multicast/multicast-listen.c.html) (with minor changes: The bind-ip was changed to `IPADDR_ANY`) worked as expected before I upgraded to macOS Big Sur.

```c
/**************************************************************/
/* Multicast listener (server)                                */
/*                                                            */
/* Activation using: {program name} {Multicast IP} {port}     */
/*   {program name} - This program name                       */
/*   {Multicast IP} - The IP address to listen to (Class D)   */
/*   {port} - The port hnumber to listen on                   */
/*                                                            */
/* This is free software released under the GPL license.      */
/* See the GNU GPL for details.                               */
/*                                                            */
/* (c) Juan-Mariano de Goyeneche. 1998, 1999.                 */
/**************************************************************/


#include <stdio.h>          /* printf(), snprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* strtol(), exit() */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>     /* socket(), setsockopt(), bind(), recvfrom(), sendto() */
#include <errno.h>          /* perror() */
#include <netinet/in.h>     /* IPPROTO_IP, sockaddr_in, htons(), htonl() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>      /* inet_addr() */
#include <unistd.h>         /* fork(), sleep() */
#include <sys/utsname.h>    /* uname() */
#include <string.h>         /* memset() */

#define MAXLEN 1024


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  u_char no = 0;
  u_int yes = 1;      /* Used with SO_REUSEADDR.
                             In Linux both u_int */
  /* and u_char are valid. */
  int send_s, recv_s;     /* Sockets for sending and receiving. */
  u_char ttl;
  struct sockaddr_in mcast_group;
  struct ip_mreq mreq;
  struct utsname name;
  int n;
  socklen_t socklen;
  struct sockaddr_in from;
  char message [MAXLEN+1];

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s mcast_group port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  memset(&mcast_group, 0, sizeof(mcast_group));
  mcast_group.sin_family = AF_INET;
  mcast_group.sin_port = htons((unsigned short int)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0));
  mcast_group.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  if ( (recv_s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror ("recv socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (setsockopt(recv_s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
    perror("reuseaddr setsockopt");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (bind(recv_s, (struct sockaddr*)&mcast_group, sizeof(mcast_group)) < 0) {
    perror ("bind");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct in_addr sin;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &sin);
  /* Preparatios for using Multicast */
  mreq.imr_multiaddr = sin;
  mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = 0;

  /* Tell the kernel we want to join that multicast group. */
  if (setsockopt(recv_s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
    perror ("add_membership setsockopt");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (;;) {
    socklen=sizeof(from);
    if ( (n=recvfrom(recv_s, message, MAXLEN, 0,
                     (struct sockaddr*)&from, &socklen)) < 0) {
      perror ("recv");
      exit(1);
    }
    message[n] = '\0'; /* null-terminate string */
    printf("%s: Received message from %s, size=%d !!\n",
           name.nodename,
           inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), n);
    printf("\t%s \n", message);
  }
}
```

Now I try to get it running again and I can not find any reason why this does not work anymore.
Did some policies change in Big Sur and this is some permission error? I already run the Application as root with `sudo ./multicast-listen 239.255.255.250 1900` but this did not work either. I'm trying to receive SSDP packages.

Comment: The wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol describes a ddos attack for this. With the macOS update, perhaps they disabled it by default. Is this [still] enabled in your firewall(s)? Because this is a site-local address, you ought to be able to create a sender program to test things with. Do you have access to another system on the same network that you can run the program(s) on (e.g. linux)? Since this is site-local, are you sure the sender program [on another system] is still running?

Comment: Hey @CraigEstey thanks for your suggestions. I see all the packages I'm interested at least in Wireshark. IIRC Wireshark sees the packages "before" the firewall. Your comment brought me to my thoughts which solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the comment of @CraigEstey brought me to the conclusion it has to do something with the Firewall. Indeed it was a simple firewall issue. In `Settings` -> `Security` -> `Firewall` -> `Firewall Options...` you have to disable `Block all incoming connections` and disable stealth mode. Now I'm receiving all SSDP packages as intended.

Comment: I'm having trouble receiving multicast packets in a Java application on Big Sur.  This did not solve my problem, as the firewall was disabled completely.  Still no multicast packets.  It seems macOS is really horrible with multicast.  Multicast works flawlessly without additional configuration in Windows.

Comment: @moonlightcheese I don't know networking with Java very well. But in Linux as well as macOS you have to register your app to the multicast group additional to the opening of the socket. See the part with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` and setsocktop. Im pretty sure you have to do something similar in java.